# Log4j file size

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j for logging of my Java project. I am creating three types of log files called "info","debug" and "error". I have set the option of max size of each file. But they are not limiting the size as we have set.

Code for debug file is -

```
public class DebugAppender extends RollingFileAppender {

    /** Creates a new instance of DebugAppender */
    public DebugAppender(String debuglogname, String path, String logfilesize) {
        String Filename = null;
        if (path == null || path.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Filename = "Logs" + File.separator + debuglogname + ".log";
        } else {
            Filename = path + File.separator + "Logs" + File.separator + debuglogname + ".log";
        }
        super.setFile(Filename);
        setMaxFileSize(logfilesize);
        setMaxBackupIndex(2);
        setAppend(true);
        setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{DATE}  %-5p %c{1} : %m%n"));
        activateOptions();
    }

    public String getFName() {
        return super.getFile();
    }
}
```

Calling of Debug logger is -

```
Logger debugLogger = Logger.getLogger(LogHandler.class.getName() + "Debug");
DebugAppender objDebugAppender = new DebugAppender(debugFileName, sTempPath, "1MB");
debugLogger.addAppender(objDebugAppender);
```

We are setting its size to "1MB", but they all three files are not limiting to 1 MB, they get exceed to GBs. How can I limit their size. If any setting needed to set then please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I've never set the log file size limit from code, have you looked into setting it from the log4j.properties config file?

Comment: I would include an example of your call to the `DebugAppender` constructor - perhaps there is an error in how you are specifying the size?

Comment: Yes, we are creating a common log file by using log4j.properties, did you know how to add for properties for multiple files (info,debug and error).

Comment: I wouldn't have multiple files as this makes it very hard to determine the exact order these messages occurred. e.g. it is usually useful to know what info and debug messages were printed before an error.  I would set the max files size to 1 MG, more like 1 GB unless you have a mobile device.  BTW If you writing GBs then it is likely you are producing too much logs.  I suggest you cut it down to just the logs you are likely to want to read.

Comment: @DuncanJones I have updated question, added calling of constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the file size of the log file through log4j properties file

```
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the xml format it would be

```
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB" />  
<param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1" />
```